# How is the tk funktion "tkwait window name" used in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I have seen this code documented in the tk docs, but I can't figure out how to do it with Ruby/Tk. Any Ideas?

http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/tkwait.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The really simple answer is: window.wait_window.